# Problem writing cin.get() for receiving an array of characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to write a semi exel console app with C++.
I write a while loop and I am trying to receive a command from the user with `cin.get()` then put it in an array of characters.  But when I write `cin.get(str, 10, '\n');` it goes into an infinite loop.

What do I need to do to fix this?

```
while (true) {
    cout << "select your choice : \n" << "1-number  2-command\n";
    cin >> n;

    switch (n) {
    case 1:
        cout << "enter row " << x + 1 << " calum : " << y + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> arr[x][y];
            system("cls");
            print(arr);
            continue;

    case 2:
        cout << "enter your command : ";
        cin.get(str, 10, '\n');
        if (str[0] == 'g') {
            for (char i = 'a'; i <= 't'; i++) {
                if (str[6] == i) {
                    switch (i) {
                    case 'a': y = 0; break;
                    case 'b': y = 1; break;
                    case 'c': y = 2; break;
                    case 'd': y = 3; break;
                    case 'e': y = 4; break;
                    case 'f': y = 5; break;
                    case 'g': y = 6; break;
                    case 'h': y = 7; break;
                    case 'i': y = 8; break;
                    case 'j': y = 9; break;
                    case 'k': y = 10; break;
                    case 'l': y = 11; break;
                    case 'm': y = 12; break;
                    case 'n': y = 13; break;
                    case '0': y = 14; break;
                    case 'p': y = 15; break;
                    case 'q': y = 16; break;
                    case 'r': y = 17; break;
                    case 's': y = 18; break;
                    case 't': y = 19; break;
                    }

                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            for (char i = '1'; i <= '20'; i++) {
                if (str[7] == i)
                    x = int(i) - 49;

    }
            system("cls");
            print(arr);
            continue;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Your **entire** `switch` can be replaced with `y = i - 'a';`. Plus, you have `case '0'` instead of `case 'o'` - I believe that's a typo.

Comment: You have `case '0': y = 14; break;` — that's inconsistent with the letters in the cases around that one.  Checking `str[0]` and `str[6]` is odd coding.  The whole switch can probably be reduced to `y = str[6] - 'a';` (though you'd probably want to validate `str[6]` first: `if (str[6] >= 'a' && str[6] <= 't') { …OK… } else { …handle error… }`).  And the loop around the remnants of the switch becomes immaterial too.  You're making your life unnecessarily complicated!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a "semi exel console app"?

Comment: its a consol app that must work like exel it has 20 Rows and 20 columns name 1 to 20 and A to T. user can input numbers in them and use commends like goto A6 to change the active array to row 6 column 1 and  like sum A7:B3 to calculate the sum for two numbers and put them in the active array.

Comment: Thanks for your help but whai can i do to prevent the infinite while loop? i wanna keep it going untie the user enter exit but if user enter a commend i want to continue the loop and start over by asking : select your choice

Comment: AS far as I'm concerned, you should set the statement to exit the loop.** i think the compiler should stop when gets to cin.get() and receive the amount then continue ** I suggest you could try to use:`while(cin.get(str, 10, '\n')){do something;}`

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will always be true, because that's what you set the conditions as. You might want to create a boolean statement that can be false so you can exit the loop, or maybe a break statement.

Comment: i wanna keep the loop going untilthe user enter exit

Comment: and i think the compiler should stop when gets to cin.get() and receive the amount then continue but it instantly goes to infinite loop.